# How to decrypt a MAPI IMessage

Tags: c++, encryption, com, atl, mapi

I have a MAPI IMessage object from a third party library, what i need is to decrypt the message (assuming it is smime), producing another decrypted MAPI object (or overriding the existing one). please recommend a way to do so. 
One way to do it, is by using IConverterSession converting MAPI to MIME string and then doing the decryption in whatever way using that mime, and then converting back the decrypted mime into MAPI IMessage. but i am looking for another way possible without this conversion, using MAPI Imessage itself. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How was the message encrypted? Messages encrypted/signed by Outlook store their (encrypt3d) data in a p7m attachment. You can extract and decrypt it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it is encrypted using outlook. i know how smime works, i was able to do so, what i want is how to save it back as an (unencrypted) mapi message again. it does not make sense to me to decrypt the p7m, and save it as attachment again to the MAPI, what i want is to alter the MAPI totally to be a normal message in its store. i can explain more if needed.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the problem is - extract the message body and set the PR_BODY property, etc. Make sure the message class is reset to IPM.Note.

Comment: i am really sorry, i am new to MAPI, but i think you understood my question, is there any other properties in MAPI to be changed other than the message class (and the PR_BODY of course). is it that easy? i also have to copy attachments (attachments within the encrypted data) to the attachment table of MAPI, correct?

Comment: Are you trying to convert an encrypted/signed message into a regular one? Take the p7m attachment, extract all the relevant information, overwrite all the relevant properties on the new message or create a new message and set the needed properties there.